# How to maintain the same copy of ArrayList among numerous objects

Tags: java, arraylist, global-variables

I am attempting to create a simple program for a card game in Java. In order to simulate the deck of cards, I plan to have an `ArrayList` in order to hold the cards, to ensure that no cards are repeated. I would like to use this `ArrayList` in multiple classes, but don't know if it is possible to do so. I know that I can work around this issue by having each class send variables back to the main class and editing the `ArrayList` there, but was wondering if it was possible to simply declare the list globally for easy access.

Comment: Either pass the reference of your main class to the other classes or make the list static.

Comment: Hey Jacob, just make the ArrayList static, that'd ensure there's only one copy of the Arraylist.. no matter how many classes (objects?) are created.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? Asides the poor presentation, the question isn't useless. This is a problem almost every Java beginner runs into at some point.

Comment: I tend to disagree with most answers here; a `static` variable may not be the best idea. I suggest you create a class `DeckOfCards`. This class will hold the (private) list of cards. There should be a public function `getNextCard()`. You will also probably have a `Dealer` class. This will hold the deck and give cards out to the players. The players don't need to access the deck - just the dealer does.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of OOP is to keep attributes of objects private, so nobody can acces them directly from the outside. Here what you can do, as mentioned in a comment above you can pass you list of cards as a parameter to methods or classes using the list. Since Java is OOP language I would not go for public declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'd need to make it public static and inside a visible class.
Like this:

```
public class Main{

    public static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

}
```

Then, you can access it by:

```
Main.cards.add(new Card());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make something like this:

```
public class Card{

public static ArrayList list;

(...)

}
```

then in your main code:

```
Card cards = new Card();
```

call it by typing

```
cards.list();
```

Comment: It's actually `cards.list;`

Comment: Really actually it's `Card.list` (static access). There's no need for `Card cards = new Card();`

Comment: @Izruo I work better with object oriented programming that's why I did this

Answer (score 0):

> ...but was wondering if it was possible to simply declare the list globally for easy access.

Of course! That's what the `static` keyword is used for. If you make your ArrayList static, there'd be only one copy of the ArrayList, regardless of the number of objects created. You can write your code as shown below:

```
public class Card{

  public static ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();

  //The rest of your code: methods, interfaces, etc.

}
```

This way, even if you create multiple objects of class Card, you only have one ArrayList to worry about.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!